# Firebase.push failed: first argument contains an invalid key ($$hashKey)

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I recently started learning AngularJS+Firebase. I'm trying to write in my firebase an object like this:

```
{
    title: "Personal Information",
    say: [
        [{ "eng": "What's", "ukr": "Що є" }, { "eng": "your", "ukr": "твоє" }, { "eng": "surname?", "ukr": "прізвище?" }],
        [{ "eng": "Smith", "ukr": "Сміт" }],
        [{ "eng": "What's", "ukr": "Що є" }, { "eng": "your", "ukr": "твоє" }, { "eng": "first", "ukr": "перше" }, { "eng": "name?", "ukr": "ім'я?(не фамілія)" }]
    ]
}
```

with line:

```
lessondata.add($scope.topic);
```

where 'lessondata' is service created with angularFireCollection() and $scope.topic - object bound to my UI.
But got the following error:
*Firebase.push failed: first argument contains an invalid key ($$hashKey) in property 'say.0.0'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"*

---

As I understood Firebase do not allow to use 0 as a key even if it's a key in an attached array for which zero key is natural. So should I change my object structure in some hardcoded instance or I miss something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25):

EDIT: As Anant points out in the comments, in the latest stable version of Angular (1.0.7 atm), you can use `angular.copy(obj)` to remove `$$hashkey` attributes.

Like Michael said, the '$' in '$$hashKey' is the issue. Angular creates the `$$hashKey` properties behind the scenes (see more here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/pI0IgNHKjxw). I've gotten around this issue by doing something like `myRef.push(angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(myAngularObject)))`.

Comment: angular.copy() should get rid of the $$hashKey property as well.

Comment: Nice. This helped me when iteratively showing data with ng-repeat before pushing data to fb. It's pretty hackish though. =/

Answer (score 6):

The issue is the $ in "$$hashKey", not the 0.  0 is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to throw another answer in here that is much simpler, just use `track by` in your repeat. It will get rid of the `$$hashKey` attribute that is causing so much grief.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Works flawlessly.  I don't even know what $index is but I just repeated the "track by $index" and it was enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this but I thought I would like to add my two cents as I was shaking my head to all the other answers. Hopefully this can help you to avoid this issue all together.

**Use the angularFire library** intended to handle angular data and use it's methods.

while yes you can use the pure javascript library methods to `.push() .add() .update()`, `.set()` ect.

So if you want to avoid any clashes when firebase communicates with angular javascript **you need to be using the appropriate `.$foo()` methods** (i.e. `.$save()`). In your case just add the `$` to your `.add()` (make it `.$add()`)

so use `lessondata.$add($scope.topic);`

**differences when saving with firebase's vs angularfire's**

---

**AngularFire's `$save()` method is implemented using Firebase's `set()` method.**

**Firebase's `push()` operation corresponds to AngularFire's `$add()` method**

Typically you should be using set()/$save() if you either have an object that already exists in the database or if you are working with objects that have a natural key.
more info on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959496/4642530

**Things to note with AngularFire**

---

For a callback:

and if you want a callback to know if your data saved correctly you can do something like this:

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
  var id = ref.key();
  console.log("added record with id " + id);
  list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
});
```

I was surprised this wasn't mentioned earlier in any of the other answers, but take a look at these docs https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get rid of the $$hasKeys is to use "track by" in ng-repeats as in the following (as mentioned in the answer above)

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj track by $index"> ... </div>
```

but you can also set track as par of ng-model-options

```
ng-model-options="{ trackBy: '$value.someKeyOnYourObject' }"
```

on a form control. This way also improves performance of your angular app.

Another way is to remove the $$hashKey is using

`angular.copy(someObj);`

If all else fails, you could also use lodash to remove the keys that start with the "$".

```
_.omitBy(yourObject, function(value, key){return _.startsWith(key, '$');});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also strip out the property before pushing it.

```
delete $scope.topic.$$hashKey
```