# Array of literals vs. Array of objects in AngularFireCollection

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a angularFireCollection that works when the AngularFireItem has strings ('Jack') in an array, but it will not allow me to update the item when objects (i.e {text:Jack, level:10}) are stored in the array.

The error is:

> Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains an invalid key ($$hashKey) in property 'skills.2'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

I suspect that this because the object has the $$hasKey in it.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: How are you attempting to set it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase.push failed: first argument contains an invalid key ($$hashKey)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680131/firebase-push-failed-first-argument-contains-an-invalid-key-hashkey)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680131/firebase-push-failed-first-argument-contains-an-invalid-key-hashkey. How are you storing objects in the array?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code snippet that adds the object?