# Firebase push() vs Angularfire $save()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How does angularfire .$save() compare to firebase .push()?  I know push() will generate a unique key when data is stored, but I can't recreate the behavior using angularfire.  Is there a way or should I be using .push() and if so, in what case would you use $save()?

Here is one sample I have using $save()...

```
        var fb = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI).child('Test');
        var article = $firebaseObject(fb);

        article.Foo = "bar";
        article.$save().then(function(fb) {
            console.log(fb.key() === article.$id); // true
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });
```

And another using .push()...

```
        var article = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI).child('Articles');

        article.push({
            title:   $scope.article.title,
            post:    $scope.article.post
        }, function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error:", error);
            }
        });
```

What are the Pros/Cons and use cases for both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How push/$add and set/$save relate

AngularFire's `$save()` method is implemented using Firebase's `set()` method. Both save data to an existing/known location.

Firebase's `push()` operation corresponds to AngularFire's `$add()` method. Both will generate a new unique child key, which means you can use them to add new data at a location that is guaranteed to not conflict with any existing data.

### When to use push and when to use set

*While the above is a hard truth, this bit is more subjective. So don't blindly copy it, but figure out how it applies to your situation.*

Typically you should be using `set()`/`$save()` if you either have an object that already exists in the database *or* if you are working with objects that have a natural key.

If the items don't have a natural key or you want them to be sorted "chronologically", you'll typically use `push()`/`$add()` to generate a key for you. This will ensure that the items are stored under a unique key and that newer items show up later in the list.

So if you're working with users, you'll typically store then under their `uid` using something like `ref.child('users').child(user.uid).set(user)`. On the other hand, if you're adding chat message to a chat room, you'll use something like `ref.child('chat').push({ name: 'Adam Youngers', 'Firebase push() vs Angularfire $save()' })`.

Comment: Great answer.   Could you also explain what the benefits are of using angular fire vs just using firebase's built in methods in an angular app?

Comment: AngularFire helps a lot in the binding of Firebase data to AngularJS views. It handles amongst other things the important task of notifying AngularJS when there is a change to the data, so that it can update the views. In the way of sending updates I personally don't have a preference for using AngularFire or the JavaScript methods directly. Luckily the two interoperate perfectly, so it's really up to you to choose what you prefer.

Comment: On a similar note, is there any feedback you can provide on [Saving structured data in firebase with angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964609/saving-structured-data-in-firebase-with-angular)