# Saving structured data in firebase with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I understand the concepts and best practices of saving [structured data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) in firebase, but I'm not clear on how to go about actually saving the data to multiple locations and providing the cross references needed.

```
{
  articles: {
    -KBX5TurV9uJTeiR26-N: {
       title: 'post title 1',
       body: 'post body goes here',
       imagesRef: {
          -KBX5XOYASP7h2ZPOKmg: true
       }
    },
    -KCe7cy6QC29WRYap0D1: {
       title: 'post title 2',
       body: 'post body goes here',
       imagesRef: {
          -KBX5XOYASP7h2ZPOKmg: true
       }
    }
  }
  images: {
    -KBX5XOYASP7h2ZPOKmg: {
       image: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhZABkAOYAAPj4...',
       articlesRef: {
          -KBX5TurV9uJTeiR26-N: true,
          -KCe7cy6QC29WRYap0D1: true
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The above schema is an example of what I am going for.  On submit of a form consisting of a title, body and image field, I need to post the title and body to the articles object, then post image to the images object, then update the imagesRef and articlesRef objects with cross references. What is the best way to go about this in Angular.  I also have angularfire as part of the project.

I'm new to angular and firebase but I think I would need to do two posts one to articles and one to images to save them and generate the unique ids.  I would then need to some how wait for both to succeed, grab the unique ids and do and update on both objects to save the cross references.  Here is what I have so far, but not sure how to take it further...

```
     $scope.AddPost = function(){

        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);
        var newArticleRef = ref.child('articles').push();
        var newArticleKey = newArticleRef.key();

        // Create the data we want to update
        var addNewPost = {};
        addNewPost["articles/" + newArticleKey] = {
            title:   $scope.article.title,
            post:    $scope.article.post
        };

        if ($scope.image) {

            var newImageRef = ref.child('images').push();
            var newImageKey = newImageRef.key();

            // Add image...
            addNewPost['images/' + newImageKey] = {
                image: $scope.image
            };

            //Add article ref...
            addNewPost['images/' + newImageKey + '/articles/' + newArticleKey] = true;

            //Add cross ref to article...
            addNewPost['articles/' + newArticleKey + '/image/' + newImageKey] = true;

        }


        // Do a deep-path update
        ref.update(addNewPost, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Error:", error);
                }
        });

    });
```

**UPDATE:** I updated the code sample to make use of [multi-location updates](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html) and the [fan-out approach](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html), but I'm getting an error on save...

```
Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains a path /images/-KCpx-Pj9oMM-EWN9irS that is ancestor of another path /images/-KCpx-Pj9oMM-EWN9irS/articles/-KCpx-Pj9oMM-EWN9irR
at Error (native)
at ig (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/plugins.js:430:390)
at jg (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/plugins.js:431:383)
at X.update (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/plugins.js:564:369)
at r.$scope.AddPost (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/app.js:171:17)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/plugins.js:216:110), <anonymous>:4:212)
at e (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/plugins.js:257:177)
at r.$eval (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/plugins.js:133:446)
at r.$apply (http://localhost:8000/app/assets/js/plugins.js:134:175)
at r.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1427:22)
```

**WARNING:**  I tried the following.  It created a single object and did not trigger a JS error, but it wiped out my DB leaving only the newly created object. Didn't lose much as I'm just running some tests right now, but thought that I should warn others.  Do Not Do this...

```
        addNewPost.Articles = {};
        addNewPost.Articles[newArticleKey] = {};
        addNewPost.Articles[newArticleKey].title = $scope.article.title;
        addNewPost.Articles[newArticleKey].post = $scope.article.post;

        var newImageRef = ref.child('images').push();
        var newImageKey = newImageRef.key();

        addNewPost.images = {};
        addNewPost.images[newImageKey] = {};
        addNewPost.images[newImageKey].image = $scope.image;
        addNewPost.images[newImageKey].articles = {};
        addNewPost.images[newImageKey].articles[newArticleKey] = true;

        addNewPost.Articles[newArticleKey].image = {};
        addNewPost.Articles[newArticleKey].image[newImageKey] = true;
```

Comment: See [Introducing multi-location updates](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html) and [Client-side fan-out for data consistency](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html)

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, this seems like exactly what I was looking for.  I tried plugging it in, but now I'm getting a First argument contains path this is ancestor of another path error.  Did I miss something?

Comment: It means that have two overlapping paths in the update. E.g. `"/posts/bla": { body: "Nanana", title: "Blablabla" }` and `"/posts/bla/author" : auth.uid`. You'll either need to merge the updates into a single path or split them to be all separate properties. This is a completely separate questions btw.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I debated about splitting it off as a new question.   I kept it part of this thread as I'm still trying to find a solution to save structured data in firebase using angular.  The articles you provided seem to be an answer but I haven't been able to successfully save data in the desired format I mentioned above.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  If you want to post the links above as an answer I can give you credit.  Otherwise I'll hold out and see if anyone suggests a better option than the one I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure its the best answer, but I found the following worked for me. It makes use of Frank van Puffelen's suggestion to use Multi-location updates. The following code was setup to support adding a new image, using an existing image or no image at all. I figure the same could apply to any meta data be in categories, tags, or users.

```
    .controller('AddPostController', ['$scope','$firebaseArray','FIREBASE_URI',
    function($scope,$firebaseArray,FIREBASE_URI) {

        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);

        $scope.AddPost = function(){

            var newArticleRef = ref.child('articles').push();
            var newArticleKey = newArticleRef.key();

            var newImageRef = ref.child('images').push();
            var newImageKey = newImageRef.key();

            // Create the data we want to update
            var addNewPost = {};

            // Add new article...
            addNewPost["articles/" + newArticleKey] = {
                title:   $scope.article.title,
                post:    $scope.article.post,
                emailId: user,
                '.priority': user
            };

            if ($scope.image) {

                // Add new image reference to new article...
                addNewPost["articles/" + newArticleKey].image = {};
                addNewPost["articles/" + newArticleKey].image[newImageKey] = true;

                // Add new image...
                addNewPost['images/' + newImageKey] = {
                    image: $scope.image,
                    emailId: user,
                    '.priority': user
                };

                // Add article reference to new image...
                addNewPost['images/' + newImageKey].articles = {};
                addNewPost['images/' + newImageKey].articles[newArticleKey] = true;

            } else if ($scope.article.image) {

                // Add existing image reference to article...
                addNewPost["articles/" + newArticleKey].image = {};
                addNewPost["articles/" + newArticleKey].image[$scope.article.image] = true;

                // Add new article reference to existing image...
                addNewPost['images/' + $scope.article.image + '/articles/' + newArticleKey] = true;

            }

            // Do a deep-path update
            ref.update(addNewPost, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Error:", error);
                }
            });

        };

    }]);
```